# Comprehensive guide on common lisp types

Tags: types, common-lisp, slots, clos

Maybe this question is too general, nevertheless i'll try:
Is there any comprehensive guide on types in common lisp?

I'm kind of confused about this subject:

Why are non-primitive types declared in `make-array`'s `:element-type` are promoted to `t`? Is there any possibility for compile-time or runtime checks of the real declared type?

Why are CLOS slot defined types don't work as constraints, allowing to put value of any type into the slot? Again, what about the checks?

The same for the functions' types declarations with `declare`.. Are they just the optimization hints to the compiler?

Also, can I use custom type specifiers, including `satisfies` in forementioned places for some robust checks, or they could only be used for explicit checks with `typep` e.t.c?

As you can see, i've got some mess in my head, so would really appreciate any neat guide (or a set of guides).

I'm on SBCL, but would also be glad to know about differences between implementations.

Comment: There are probably too many questions in this one question, which makes this a bit too broad.  But the comprehensive guide is probably just a selection of parts from the HyperSpec.  E.g., for type declarations, you'd look at [Declaration TYPE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/d_type.htm), which describes exactly what a type declaration means (pretty much that you have undefined behavior if the value of the variable isn't actually that type).  But undefined behavior can be useful, because the compiler could: (i) insert type checks to provide safety and let you know if...

Comment: things go wrong; or (ii) use optimized code that *won't* check types, because you're promising the value will be of the correct type.  Which it will do could depend on other declarations, such as the value of any [OPTIMIZE declarations](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/d_optimi.htm#safety).

Comment: Another part of the HyperSpec that might be  part of the "comprehensive guide" would be chapter [4. Types and Classes](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/04_.htm).  That section is actually a bit thin in content, but links to just about all the relevant entries (e.g., where types get used, what can define them, how they're used, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! hyperspec is nice, but it doesn't really answer all by questions: like the one about type in `make-array` or type of slot.. or maybe I just haven't noticed..

Comment: The entry on [**defclass**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_defcla.htm#defclass) describes the meaning of the **:type** option: "The :type slot option specifies that the contents of the slot will always be of the specified data type. It effectively declares the result type of the reader generic function when applied to an object of this class. The consequences of attempting to store in a slot a value that does not satisfy the type of the slot are undefined. The :type slot option is further discussed in Section 7.5.3 (Inheritance of Slots and Slot Options)."

Comment: That description says that (i) you might want to look at 7.5.3 for some more about that option, and more importantly (ii) that (ii.a) "It effectively declares the result type of the reader generic function when applied to an object of this class" and (ii.b) storing a value of a different type has undefined consequences. So at this point, you just need to find out what effects declaring the result type of a (generic) function has, and what undefined consequences might occur if you try to store a different type of value (and that might depend on optimize declarations, etc.).

Comment: Have also a look at https://sellout.github.io/2012/03/03/common-lisp-type-hierarchy/

Comment: @coredump , wow! this one is also one of the things i wanted to ask for, but was too shy to )

Comment: @Coredump that's a very nice resource.  If you made that, well done; if not,  good find!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks, that's not mine but I really like it too. I moved the link to the answer in case comments get deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler to optimize for safety if you want it to actually enforce the types:

```
CL-USER> (declaim (optimize (safety 3)))
NIL
CL-USER> (defclass foobar () ())
#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::FOOBAR>
CL-USER> (defun foo (a)
           (make-array 1 :element-type 'foobar
                         :initial-contents (list a)))
FOO
CL-USER> (foo (make-instance 'foobar))
#(#<FOOBAR {1005696CE3}>)
CL-USER> (foo 12)
;=> ERROR
CL-USER> (declaim (ftype (function (integer integer) integer) quux))
(QUUX)
CL-USER> (defun quux (a b)
           (+ a b))
QUUX
CL-USER> (quux 12 12)
24 (5 bits, #x18, #o30, #b11000)
CL-USER> (quux 12 "asd")
;=> ERROR
```

Checking the types at run-time adds some overhead (especially if it happens in a loop), and may be done multiple times for a single value, so it's not done by default.

```
(declaim (optimize (safety 3)))

(defun some-predicate-p (a)
  (format t "~&Checking type...")
  (integerp a))

(deftype foo () `(satisfies some-predicate-p))

(defclass bar ()
  ((foo :type foo :initarg :foo)))

(declaim (ftype (function (foo) list) qwerty))
(defun qwerty (foo)
  (loop repeat 10 collecting (make-instance 'bar :foo foo)))

(qwerty 12)
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
; Checking type...
;=> (#<BAR {1003BCA213}> #<BAR {1003BCA263}> #<BAR {1003BCA2B3}>
;    #<BAR {1003BCA303}> #<BAR {1003BCA353}> #<BAR {1003BCA3A3}>
;    #<BAR {1003BCA3F3}> #<BAR {1003BCA443}> #<BAR {1003BCA493}>
;    #<BAR {1003BCA4E3}>)
```

If you want a function to always check the type of a place, regardless of the optimization settings, you should use [`CHECK-TYPE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_check_.htm) manually.

Comment: Nice! is it a common practice to turn on types checking for test / debug? and turn it off for production?

Comment: And more globally: is it a common practice to use types in common lisp at all? Or should I just code like in any language without type check, like JS? What is the common lisp way ideologically?

Comment: It's a good idea to have the type declarations whenever it's not too inconvenient (especially for primitive types). In development you probably should use something like `(declaim (optimize (debug 3) (safety 3) (speed 1)))`, but in production it depends on your needs. For some math-heavy piece of code you might want `(speed 3) (safety 0)`, while for a web-server where uptime is more important than speed, `(safety 3) (speed 2)` plus proper error handling could be better.

Comment: thanks! your examples really put things in order in my head a bit. I'll have to play with that for some time..

Comment: and one more question: when i execute your example with `make-array` in repl it works perfectly fine, but when i literally execute `(make-array 1 :element-type 'foobar :initial-contents (list 1))`, it creates an array without any complains. I know: noone does this in top level, but still, what is the reason for that?

Comment: When you run it directly in the REPL, SBCL doesn't bother applying the optimizations. In my example I put it inside a function since that should always be compiled and optimized properly (at least on SBCL).

Comment: Also it's worth noting that implementations are perfectly free to treat `(declaim (optimize safety))` as a comment if they want.

Answer (score 5):

> Why are non-primitive types declared in make-array's :element-type are promoted to t? Is there any possibility for compile-time or runtime checks of the real declared type?

The `:element-type` parameter is there that an implementation can choose an optimized memory layout for an array - mostly for saving memory space. This is typically useful with primitive types. For other types most Common Lisp runtimes will have no optimized storage implementation and thus the declaration will have no useful effect.

> Why are CLOS slot defined types don't work as constraints, allowing to put value of any type into the slot? Again, what about the checks?

An implementation may do that.

Clozure CL:

```
? (defclass foo () ((bar :type integer :initform 0 :initarg :bar)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO>
? (make-instance 'foo :bar "baz")
> Error: The value "baz", derived from the initarg :BAR,
  can not be used to set the value of the slot BAR in
  #<FOO #x302000D3EC3D>, because it is not of type INTEGER.
```

> The same for the functions' types declarations with declare.. Are they just the optimization hints to the compiler?

The type declarations with declare can be ignored - for example in Symbolics Genera most declarations will be ignored. Implementations are not required to process them. Most implementations will at least interpret them as assurance that some object will be of that type and create optimized code for that - possibly without runtime checks and/or specialized code for that type. But it's usually necessary to set corresponding optimization levels (speed, safety, debug, ...)

Additionally compilers derived from CMUCL's compiler (SBCL, ...) may use them for some compile time checks.

But none of the effects is specified in the ANSI CL standard. The standard provides the declarations and leaves the interpretation to the implementations.

Answer (score 3):

How types are handled during compilation is defined by implementations. In the case of SBCL, types are generally treated as assertions, but the actual behavior depends on optimisation levels.

Types as assertions means that if a function takes a  number `n` and produces a string `s`, you generally don't *assume* that `n` is a number. Instead, what you have is a *guarantee* that *if* the function returns, then `n` effectively was a number and `s` is now a string. But if you reuse `s`, your compiler has an opportunity to skip a check for `s` being a string. This is generally what you want because your functions are available globally and can thus be called from anywhere. Since functions are responsible for checking their inputs, it is normal that you always check for `n` being a number first.

Yet, type declarations for functions can help you in case you call a function in a context where it can be proved that types will certainly mismatch at runtime (the intersection of types is empty). In order to trust type assertions blindly, you have to lower the safety levels.

Note: I originally posted it at a comment, but in order to avoid it being deleted, here is a link to a nice graphics representing relationships between types in CL:

http://sellout.github.io/2012/03/03/common-lisp-type-hierarchy